# Enable the option to rightclick on welcomemenu links so I can open them in a new tab if I want to?

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-controls

Is this possible? I have created a custom controltemplate and want the url here to have the option to be opened in a new tab. (right now you cant rightclick on the link at all?)

my control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomAction
  Id="customWMItem"
  GroupId="PersonalActions"
  Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
  Sequence="300"
  Title="Mitt dokumentbibliotek"
  Description="Mitt dokumentbibliotek">

<UrlAction Url="/_layouts/15/MySite.aspx?MySiteRedirect=AllDocuments"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't enable right click, rather you can use `JavaScript` along with `UrlAction` to always open in a new tab.

```
<UrlAction Url="javascript:void(window.open('/_layouts/15/MySite.aspx?MySiteRedirect=AllDocuments','_blank'))"/>
```